# CURL Got 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, curl

Hi I have problem with CURL rumah.com. I have set everything completely but still got 403 http code.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://rumah.com');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookieRead);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Safari/605.1.15');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,'https://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,20);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Is there something am I missing? Thank you

Comment: They have CloudFlare, it's blocking you since you're a bot.

Comment: Do you know how to bypass it? It seems they require javascript turned on and curl does not. How to spoof it in CURL?